# Pandas pipe a list of functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written the following code to pipe some transformations of a dataset:

```
def func(self,df):
    ...
    return (df.pipe(self.transformations[0])
              .pipe(self.transformations[1]
              .
              .pipe(self.transformations[n])
```

I'd like to rewrite it in a more pythonic way, abstracting away from the number of elements in the list transformations, so to not have to hard code the transformations, but just add them to the list.

I thought about a for loop in which I update the dataframe at each iteration with a transformation, but I'd like a more concise way of doing this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What if you think the problem like a [Producer-Consumer Pattern](https://serengetitech.com/tech/tutorial-on-how-to-implement-producer-consumer-pattern-using-wait-and-notify-methods/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `reduce` which can replace loops and recursion much of the time.

```
from functools import reduce

def func(self, df):
    return reduce(lambda _df, trans: _df.pipe(trans), self.transformations, df)
```

Comment: This is a beautiful line of code

Answer (score 0):

I created a small package to do this for Pandas/Polars `.pipe` operations, or any other arbitrary functions: https://chris-santiago.github.io/dpipes/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34523724)

Comment: Yup, can you please expand more? Anyway it looks cool